# Changing frequency by button press

Tags: frequency

[image]I have to up the frequency by 100 hz by button press for upto 1khz; I am stuck on using the debounce source code. The problem is every time I press button the value for "i" goes to random number instead of going from 400 to 600 to 800 to 1000...to 2000.  I am using prescaler 1.
I have another question regarding the frequency. How can I get the frequency stable at 100hz per button press.

```
#define LEDPIN 7
float highTime;
float lowTime;
int freq;
float period;

//uint16_t val2= pulseIn(4, HIGH);

ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect) {
  digitalWrite(LEDPIN, !digitalRead(LEDPIN));
}
// constants won't change. They're used here to set pin numbers:
const int buttonPin = 5;    // the number of the pushbutton pin
//const int ledPin = 13;      // the number of the LED pin

// Variables will change:

int buttonState;             // the current reading from the input pin
int lastButtonState = LOW;   // the previous reading from the input pin

// the following variables are unsigned longs because the time, measured in
// milliseconds, will quickly become a bigger number than can be stored in an int.
unsigned long lastDebounceTime = 0;  // the last time the output pin was toggled
unsigned long debounceDelay = 50;    // the debounce time; increase if the output flickers

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  //pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);

  // set initial LED state
  //digitalWrite(ledPin, ledState);

  pinMode(LEDPIN, OUTPUT);
  // initialize Timer1 (the 16-bit timer) using channel A output compare

  TCCR1A = 0; // set entire TCCR1A register to 0
  TCCR1B = 0; // same for TCCR1B
  TCNT1 = 0; // initialize counter value to 0
  // set compare match register for 100 Hz increments
  OCR1A = 9999; // = 16000000 / (8 * 100) - 1 (must be <65536)
  // turn on CTC mode
  TCCR1B |= (1 << WGM12);
  // Set CS12, CS11 and CS10 bits for 1 prescaler
  TCCR1B |= (0 << CS12) | (1 << CS11) | (0 << CS10);

  // enable timer compare interrupt
  TIMSK1 |= (1 << OCIE1A);
  sei(); // allow interrupts
  interrupts(); // enable global interrupts:
}


void loop() {

  // read the state of the switch into a local variable:
  int reading = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  int MIN = 400;
  int MAX = 2000;
  int i = 0;
  int change = 200;
  int var = 16000000 / (1 * i) - 1 ;
  // check to see if you just pressed the button
  // (i.e. the input went from LOW to HIGH), and you've waited long enough
  // since the last press to ignore any noise:

  // If the switch changed, due to noise or pressing:
  if (reading != lastButtonState) {
    // reset the debouncing timer
    lastDebounceTime = millis();
  }
  for (int i = 400; i <= 2000; i += change) {
    if ((millis() - lastDebounceTime) > debounceDelay) {




      // whatever the reading is at, it's been there for longer than the debounce
      // delay, so take it as the actual current state:

      // if the button state has changed:
      if (reading != buttonState) {
        buttonState = reading;

        // only toggle the LED if the new button state is HIGH
        //for(int ii=MIN; ii<MAX; ii++){
        //


        if (buttonState == HIGH) {
          Serial.print("Value of i: ");
          Serial.println(i);

          //for(int i=MIN; i <= MAX; i+=change){
          //int var = 16000000 / (1 * (ii*2)) - 1 ;
          buttonState != buttonState;
          TCCR1A = 0; // set entire TCCR1A register to 0
          TCCR1B = 0; // same for TCCR1B
          TCNT1  = 0; // initialize counter value to 0
          OCR1A = 16000000 / (1 * i) - 1; // =  (must be <65536)
          // turn on CTC mode
          TCCR1B |= (1 << WGM12);
          // Set CS12, CS11 and CS10 bits for 1 prescaler
          TCCR1B |= (0 << CS12) | (0 << CS11) | (1 << CS10);
          // enable timer compare interrupt
          TIMSK1 |= (1 << OCIE1A);
          highTime = (pulseIn(4, HIGH));
          lowTime = (pulseIn(4, LOW));
          period = highTime + lowTime;
          freq = 1000000 / period;   //getting frequency with totalTime is in Micro seconds
          Serial.print(freq);
          Serial.print("\n");
        }
        //}
        //  }

      }
    }
  }


  // save the reading. Next time through the loop, it'll be the lastButtonState:
  lastButtonState = reading;

}
```

Comment: add a layer of separation between button press detection and the frequency adjustment ... use a flag variable ... check for button press at top of `loop()` ...  if a valid button press is detected, then set the flag ... do no other response to button press ... further down in `loop()`, check for the flag ... if it is set, then adjust frequency and clear the flag

Comment: can you show me example?

Comment: use the Bounce2 library for button handling